# Administrar BD Derby

Tags: java, derby

alguien sabe de algún cliente estilo Navicat o algo así para administrar una BD Derby... sucede que debo hacer modificaciones en la estructura de una BD que corre en este server y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo de forma gráfica, probé con NaviCat 12 pero no soporta conexiones con este sgbd. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una herramienta muy útil que se llama DBeaver, administra las siguientes bases de datos:

MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Derby, etc.

Revisa https://dbeaver.io/